# jQuery - Replace HTML content before a specific word

Tags: jquery

I have a string of text inside a div. I need all instances of ", " that exist before the text "Foo" to be replaced with a < br > tag and leave and instances of ", " after "Foo".

I would have thought the .append() function would suffice. But no dice. Any guidance would be appreciated?

HTML

```
<div>Hello, you, Foo 1, 2, 3</div>
<div>Hello, you, Foo 1, 2, 3</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(function() {
  $('div').each(function() {
    $(this).html(function() {
      return $(this).html().before("Foo").replace(/, /ig, "<br>");
    });
  });
});
```

End Result Should Be:

```
Hello
you
Foo 1, 2, 3

Hello
you
Foo 1, 2, 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this function to do the replacement, and place it inside your html generation function.

```
function replaceBefore(needle, replace, haystack, before) {
  var i = haystack.indexOf(before);
  var sub = haystack.substring(0, i);

  while (sub != sub.replace(needle, replace)) {
    sub = sub.replace(needle, replace);
  }

  return sub + haystack.substring(i);
}
```

Then call that function:

```
$(function() {
  $('div').each(function() {
    $(this).html(function() {
      return replaceBefore(', ', '<br>', $(this).html(), 'Foo');
    });
  });
});
```

Basically, getting the substring before your "Foo" and making all the replacements, then stitching the substrings back together.

Comment: I really liked your solution the best, though each solution I have see so far (Midas & Benjamin), helped me solve this problem as well. Your approach was modular by defining a recyclable function. Though I didn't originally ask for that depth, I am thankful for it.

Comment: @TGEE glad it helped!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex with lookahead:

```js
$(function() {
  $('div').each(function() {
    $(this).html(
      $(this).html().replace(/, (?=.*Foo)/ig, '<br>')
    );
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>Hello, you, Foo 1, 2, 3</div>
<div>Hello, you, Foo 1, 2, 3</div>
```

Comment: This was a very simple straight forward solution that worked, and I like this a lot - thank you. In essence you helped answer my problem and opened me up to making use of regex.

Answer (score 0):

```js
(function($)
{
    $('div').each(function()
    {
        var html = $(this).html();
        $(this).html(
            html.substring(0, html.indexOf("Foo")).replace(/,/g,'<br>')
            + html.substring(html.indexOf("Foo"))
        );
     });
})(jQuery);
```

This block of code works for me. Any luck on your end?

Comment: Just like the solution from Midas - it worked and I appreciate the simplicity of this solution - Thanks!